# Restrict interface's key types to those of another interface's values

Tags: typescript

[This playground example](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/index.html#code/JYOwLgpgTgZghgYwgAgJIBE5jsg3sgKGWTGDABsIAuZAZzClAHMBuI5RJW2geyhvqMQrAgF8CBUJFiIUqAMIRy5PIWIBtANYQAngIbMAuvqGs1yAPQW0yAO5xwJHsgAmz3gFsIpYcnLBtZC1dGgA3OHIAVwgeGDRMbHUAck4Ibj4kw2M6A2E2cQIEHhB6Vyw4Ggxy9UNkAF4g9lx2YlIKamQAIgAxYChSkDgvToAaFo4ELl5+Lpg++kHhseJRZbxxtsoaToAZOAGhiFHx1PSZztpIqEWjtfFDCSKSsGQkZVpKxWUa+sbiZuIxDm-TAN22mFCOmOgLoVzBXQAUodaJ12KsmuNgQtDtsAELAZRQtbES7XHFdeSMBDaMColYEQxAA) describes what I'm trying to do but essentially I'm trying to limit the possible keys of one object to the values on another.

Is this possible?

Answer (score 0):

The closest I can get is this

```js
type accessor = "surname" | "firstname"

interface IData { 
  title: string;
  accessor: accessor;
}

type ICell = Record<accessor, string>
```

Comment: Thanks Klas, unfortunately I don't know what the accessor values will be as I'm using generics so your solution won't be work

Comment: And you're saying that the value of `accessor` is arbitrarily given at runtime? I don't think you can base types on that. TypeScript can only act on compile time information (since it is only active during compilation)

Answer (score 0):

It's not possible in TypeScript to define types based on runtime values, as all typings are removed at runtime. What you are asking for is entirely impossible.

Consider: what if this object was fetched from a web-server which returned random values? How would compiling even work? Would you need to be connected to the internet? As there is no runtime typechecking, it simply doesn't work.

To accomplish this at runtime, like you seem to wish, you can use ordinary javascript. For example:

```
const accessors = data.map(o => o.accessor);

for (const cell of cells) {
    for (const key in cell) {
        if (!accessors.includes(key)) {
            // throw a runtime error
            throw new Error("This key is not a valid accessor!"); 
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can *kind of* do this if you know the types of `IData` in compile time. So you would need something along the lines of:

```
const data = [
  {
    title: "First name",
    accessor: "firstname",
  },
  {
    title: "Last name",
    accessor: "surname",
  }
] as const

type Accessors = typeof data[number]["accessor"]

type ICell = Record<Accessors, string>

const cells: ICell[] = [
  {
    firstname: "Davy",
    surname: "James"
  },
  {
    firstname: "Billy",
    surname: "Cricket"
  }
]
```

If you don't know the structure of `data` in compile time, like other answers have pointed out, you can't do this. Also (like any other object) you would have to check that any other data created at runtime fits the `ICell` data type and you can't actually check it in runtime if that's what you're trying to do.