# Infer a type key from another object's values

Tags: javascript, typescript, type-inference

I have a interface column.

```
interface column {
  field: string
  label: string
}
```

So a row of columns would be:

```
const cols = [{
    label: 'First Name',
    field: 'fname',
  },
  {
    label: 'Last Name',
    field: 'lname',
  },
  {
    label: 'Email',
    field: 'email',
  }]
```

Data would be an array of data rows.

```
const data:{}[] = [{
fname: 'bob', lname: 'dylan', email: 'db@email.com',
fname: 'van', lname: 'halen', email: 'vh@email.com'
}]
```

Is there a way to enforce keys ie [fname, lname, email] of data to be the values of corresponding cols[n]['field']??
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you can do this as long as you define `cols` in such a way so that the compiler doesn't widen the `field` properties to `string`.  The easiest way to do that with TS3.4+ is to use a [`const` assertion](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-3-4.html#const-assertions):

```
const cols = [{
  label: 'First Name',
  field: 'fname',
},
{
  label: 'Last Name',
  field: 'lname',
},
{
  label: 'Email',
  field: 'email',
}] as const;
```

That `as const` means that `cols` will be considered a readonly tuple where the `label` and `field` properties have [string literal](http://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/advanced-types.html#string-literal-types) types.

From there you can make a type alias that converts a set of `Column`-compatible values to an object type with the `field` properties as keys.  Of course there's no mention of what the value type of each field should be, so I'm assuming it's always `string`:

```
interface Column {
  field: string
  label: string
};

type StringObjFromColumns<T extends readonly Column[]> =
  { [K in T[number]["field"]]: string }
```

And then we can define your data type as `StringObjFromColumns<typeof cols>`:

```
const data: StringObjFromColumns<typeof cols>[] = [{
  fname: 'bob', lname: 'dylan', email: 'db@email.com',
}, {
  fname: 'van', lname: 'halen', email: 'vh@email.com'
}, {
  fname: 'van', lname: 'morrison', age: 75, email: 'vm@example.com' // error! age is extra
}, {
  fname: 'ted', lname: 'nugent' // error! email is missing
}]
```

You can see how it enforces the constraint that each object must have those three fields of type `string`.

Okay, hope that helps; good luck!

[Playground link to code](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/#code/JYOwLgpgTgZghgYwgAgMIHsA2BXAtiZAbwChlkZgJMATALmQGcwpQBzU5TOAIyvqZYh2AXwDcyYsTABPAA4oAyszYB5bgCsAYlHS4MOfAwA8AFWQQAHpBDUGyKBDjV0ITNLRY8IANoBdAHzIALwchMjeANLIoMgm3iB4vFC+3gBEFFTUqb6+-MpCyMKSCC5MyCWYdkHhJGRcvJj0AOSawFBlAHJwuBBNADQcGTTNMCDdvQPCA7WcPHzITQAycJ3j-YOUwwuYYz3rU8Qz9fNNAKK4cMCY62RDdAsQF1f7vsgr5aVgopLEJSBl1DgYDg9CUglYai0Oj0nkMRhk8nQMA+lX8fmCNUGuwgzW46G4-U42Oa1GkXBAhMel0aC2o3AAAlSrgA6Eq4fZ9IhY8bNABucApnJ2PIWAAs4JgIILzE8aU1eaLGbLWbomsQplzbsSFvzpcKes1cOgoCwGC5CXBWDjkAB2ACsnKZct5uEZFm6sklKvZyAA9L7zCbjQBCN5W6J2SzMODqzkzUYipqQaiE-XWpoJK3gJp+gPQHRQUNOiPIXDABgMNjq3xAA)

Answer (score 0):

This is not possible as typescript types are enforced at compile time and not run time. See my answer to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60916064/restrict-interfaces-key-types-to-those-of-another-interfaces-values/60918156#60918156) which answers yours.

Answer (score -1):

This is a tricky one.
Having

```
interface Column {
    field: string
    label: string
}
```

We can define a `RowObject` and, additionally, just for the sake of example, a `Row` which has the `column` property and the `row` itself.

```
interface RowObject {
    [key: string]: string;
}

interface Row {
    cols: Column[];
    object: RowObject;
}
```

Now, we should define a function to prototype the new objects.

```
const createRowBlueprint = (cols: Column[]): Row => {
    return {
        cols: [...cols],
        object: cols.map(c => c.field)
                    .reduce((prop: RowObject, prev: string) => (prop[prev] = '', prop), {})
    };
};
```

I just defined the `Row` interface to dynamically access the "real row object" properties, like so

```
const row = createRowBlueprint(cols);
row.cols.forEach(col => {
    const { field } = col;
    const value = row.object[field];
    console.log(`Field ${field} binded to ${value}`);
});
```

Given your `columns` collection, this outputs the following

```
{
  cols: [
    { label: 'First Name', field: 'fname' },
    { label: 'Last Name', field: 'lname' },
    { label: 'Email', field: 'email' }
  ],
  row: { fname: '', lname: '', email: '' }
}

Field fname binded to
Field lname binded to
Field email binded to
```

Obviously, I set the default value to an empty string. But, the prove that it works is that the value accessed from the field is not `undefined`.

Finally, this approach is not safety typed. But, as far as I know, Typescript does not support dynamic type definition in compilaiton time, for the moment... So this is a tricky workaround.

Hope it helps.